# Debugging in emacs (with gud) often results in stack overflow error

Tags: emacs, gdb

I'm getting this message in emacs when debugging:

```
error in process filter: gdb-stack-list-locals-handler: Stack overflow in regexp matcher
error in process filter: Stack overflow in regexp matcher
```

I then have to kill gdb and restart the debugging session.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can tell you that this is probably due to a regexp trying to be run over a long line. Emacs' regexp implementation is ... kinda lacking. You can do a `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and get a stack trace -- following the files there will likely lead you to the regexp culprit.

As far as working around it goes, I really don't know yet. If you find out, let me know ;)